# From Json to Object, Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

i have an Array of json objects that looks like this (but has  like 30k lines):

```
{
    "Foglio1": [
        {
            "istat": "1001",
            "cap": "10011"
        },
        {
            "istat": "1002",
            "cap": "10060"
        },
        {
            "istat": "1003",
            "cap": "10070"
        },
        {
            "istat": "1004",
            "cap": "10010"
        },
        {
            "istat": "1006",
            "cap": "10040"
        }
     ]
}
```

my classes:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("italy_cap.json"));
        String cap=reader.readLine();
        Gson g = new Gson();
        Foglio1 p=null;
        while(cap!=null) {
            p = g.fromJson(cap, Foglio1.class);
            
            cap=reader.readLine();
        }
        System.out.println(p);
        
        
    }

}
```

```
public class Foglio1 {
    ArrayList <Cap> Foglio1;
}
```

```
public class Cap {
    String istat;
    String cap;
    
    public String getIstat() {
        return istat;
    }
    public void setIstat(String istat) {
        this.istat = istat;
    }
    public String getCap() {
        return cap;
    }
    public void setCap(String cap) {
        this.cap = cap;
    }
}
```

I wanted to read the json and convert it into a java object for parsing it, but i'm not getting  how to make it work.
the error it's giving me it's:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 14 path $.Foglio1[0]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:937)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
    at net.codejava.ws.Test.main(Test.java:21)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 14 path $.Foglio1[0]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1401)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:549)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:414)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
    at `enter code here`com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
```

As alternative can you give me any ideas of libraries for big json?.

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: You can't read JSON line-by-line and try to feed snippets to it. Feed the string for the entire JSON object (the whole file `italy_cap.json`) to Gson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is not a line-oriented data format, and trying to read it line by line isn't going to work. You can just give the entire file to Gson all at once:

```
static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("italy_cap.json"))) {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        Foglio1 p = g.fromJson(reader, Foglio1.class);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

If your JSON is so big that the objects you create from it don't fit in memory, you can switch to [reading it as a stream](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming), but that may require extensive changes to the rest of your program. For example, you may have to change the list within the `Foglio1` class to something else, or get rid of the `Foglio1` class entirely. Without knowing the rest of your program, it's impossible to say.